# Coding standard and Readability: Verbose/Redundant statements vs Short/Compressed

Tags: java

I have the following 3 different versions of code.
Version 1 is overly verbose and contains redundancy but on the other hand seems easier to read. Version 2 is somewhere in the middle, and Version 3 is shortened and straight to the point.

Their all equivalent in terms of functionality. I am not sure about readability. 
According to best practices which is the best? Please add actual pros-cons based on theory.
Is there a chance situations like these are also determined by programming style and hence are opinion based as opposed to having black/white clear guidelines?

### Version 1:

```
for (int i = 0; i < resultsSize; i++)
            {   
                bundle = ja.getJSONObject(i).getString(SOLR_BUNDLEID_FIELD);
                app = DataStore.applicationsCache.get(bundle);
                if (app!=null)
                {

                    if(catalogRequest.filter.query_pub==null)
                    {
                        addApp(DataStore.applicationsCache.get(bundle),preparedApps);
                        continue;
                    }

                    if(app.vendor.equalsIgnoreCase(catalogRequest.filter.query_pub))
                        addApp(DataStore.applicationsCache.get(bundle),preparedApps);   
                }

            }
```

### Version 2:

```
for (int i = 0; i < resultsSize; i++)
            {   
                bundle = ja.getJSONObject(i).getString(SOLR_BUNDLEID_FIELD);
                app = DataStore.applicationsCache.get(bundle);
                if (app!=null)
                {
                    if(catalogRequest.filter.query_pub==null || app.vendor.equalsIgnoreCase(catalogRequest.filter.query_pub))
                    addApp(DataStore.applicationsCache.get(bundle),preparedApps);
                }

            }
```

### Version 3:

```
for (int i = 0; i < resultsSize; i++) {
                if ((app = DataStore.applicationsCache.get(ja.getJSONObject(i)
                        .getString(SOLR_BUNDLEID_FIELD))) != null
                        && (catalogRequest.filter.query_pub == null || app.vendor
                                .equalsIgnoreCase(catalogRequest.filter.query_pub)))
                    addApp(app, preparedApps);
            }
```

Comment: Asking which version is better is not a good question as it is asking directly for opinion. You could choose one and see the review of it.

Comment: @ Marc-Andre Ok..will change it to ask which is better according to coding / readability standards and why.

Comment: This type of question (A vs B [vs C]) isn't very likely to give you a useful code review, why don't you just post the version you're using, and let reviewers tell you how it would be best written? Please see our [help/on-topic] to see what we're all about - we're looking for code to be peer reviewed, not for snippets to be compared and discussed. As it stands, this question is still opinion-based.

Comment: This is still an issue of opinion. IMO, if code is *valid* then it is also *readable* but that's my opinion, and it's a pretty strong statement really. I'm basically saying "you should be able to read anything that isn't a syntax error" and we all know that within that realm some things are easier to understand than others. I personally use ternary operators and coalesce operator (??) in C#, but I've been told it's not very readable. Well, it's valid code, and to me it's *more* readable than a long IF that won't fit on my screen. I prefer example 3, but I know a lot of people who wouldn't

Answer (score 4):

Version 1 has **code duplication** for one seemingly very important line:

```
addApp(DataStore.applicationsCache.get(bundle), preparedApps);
```

Duplicating this line is not a good idea if it can be easily avoided.

---

Version 3 is using `&&` and `||` **mixed** in the same condition which makes it a lot harder to understand. Try to avoid mixing those two together, instead *extract conditions* into variables, as palacsint has done with `boolean emptyQueryPub`.

---

Version 2 is the one I like the best, but with some modifications.

Java Coding Conventions about braces is that they should be on the same line as the condition/loop and not on it's own line.

Adding a few spaces makes the code more readable.

Most IDEs has an Auto-format key-shortcut. Ctrl + Shift + F in Eclipse and Alt + Shift + F in NetBeans. I recommend using it.

The results of the above mentioned fixes:

```
for (int i = 0; i < resultsSize; i++) {
    bundle = ja.getJSONObject(i).getString(SOLR_BUNDLEID_FIELD);
    app = DataStore.applicationsCache.get(bundle);
    if (app != null) {
        if (catalogRequest.filter.query_pub == null ||
                app.vendor.equalsIgnoreCase(catalogRequest.filter.query_pub)) {
            addApp(DataStore.applicationsCache.get(bundle), preparedApps);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> Version 1 is overly verbose and contains redundancy but on the other hand seems easier to read.

I'd go with the first one with some modifications. The second one need horizontal scrolling which is hard to read. The third one was made for a computer, for humans it's too hard to follow, the condition is too complex.

> Any fool can write code that a computer can understand. Good programmers write code that humans can understand. ([Martin Fowler](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Martin_Fowler))

A few whitespace (around operators, method parameters etc.), curly braces and indentation would help:

```
for (int i = 0; i < resultsSize; i++) {   
    bundle = ja.getJSONObject(i).getString(SOLR_BUNDLEID_FIELD);
    app = DataStore.applicationsCache.get(bundle);
    if (app != null) {
        if (catalogRequest.filter.query_pub == null) {
            addApp(DataStore.applicationsCache.get(bundle),preparedApps);
            continue;
        }

        if (app.vendor.equalsIgnoreCase(catalogRequest.filter.query_pub)) {
            addApp(DataStore.applicationsCache.get(bundle), preparedApps);  
        } 
    }
}
```

The you could use some explanatory variables to explain the purpose of the conditions:

```
for (int i = 0; i < resultsSize; i++) {   
    bundle = ja.getJSONObject(i).getString(SOLR_BUNDLEID_FIELD);
    app = DataStore.applicationsCache.get(bundle);
    if (app == null) {
        continue;
    }

    String queryPub = catalogRequest.filter.query_pub; // TODO: use better name
    boolean emptyQueryPub = queryPub == null; // TODO: use better name
    boolean vendorSame = app.vendor.equalsIgnoreCase(queryPub); // TODO: use better name
    if (emptyQueryPub || sameVendor) {
        addApp(app, preparedApps);
    }
}
```

Note that `addApp` uses `app` instead of `DataStore.applicationsCache.get(bundle)` (as version 3 does) and the inverted `app != null` condition. I guess the latter is a typo in the question.

See also: *Clean Code* by *Robert C. Martin*, *G19: Use Explanatory Variables*;  *Refactoring: Improving the Design of Existing Code by Martin Fowler*, *Introduce Explaining Variable*

Comment: Ugly code ... needs to have `{` at line-end, not new-line ....

Comment: @rolfl: Yeah, I also prefer that (code changed now) but I don't have hard facts for that. *Steve McConnell* has some, rather hard to follow ones in *Code Complete 2nd Edition* (p746) and the Java Code Conventions from 1999 also suggests that. The latter is rather a mess nowadays, sometimes I find it embarrassing to quote. Do you have any good resource?

Comment: Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language [See 7.2, second bullet-point](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-142311.html#15395)

Comment: Also see the [Google Java style guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javaguide.html#s4.1.2-blocks-k-r-style)